# How to fetch/add OneDrive photo tags via API?

Tags: exif, onedrive

On the OneDrive website under Photos>Tags, it shows that it has behind-the-scenes done analysis of my photos and figured out common tags, e.g. #People, #Fireworks, #Whiteboard.

How can I access these tags programmaticaly via the OneDrive API?

It looks like they're not physically stored within the JPEG's EXIF header - at least, I didn't find them using ExifTool or the exifdata.com website. (Actually I can't even tell whether EXIF allows for arbitrary tags to be stored in it... a search for "exif tag" understandably produces the wrong results :) )

And I couldn't find any OneDrive APIs that mentioned these tags. They didn't seem to be present in any facets, for instance.

Answer (score 3):

At this point in time (February 2016), this isn't accessible via the API.

There is, however, a [UserVoice](https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/262982-onedrive/suggestions/7866669-include-tags-in-api) request to have these added to the API. On November 25, 2015, it was tagged with "In the plans" and is currently 11th on the [list of planned features](https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/262982-onedrive/status/1333583). There is not an associated ETA for when the request will be completed.

Answer (score 2):

If you add your own tags to a JPG file via the OneDrive website or iOS app, it will write them to the EXIF data in the file and update the file synced to your local file system.

I'm not sure which other file types it will do this for, but it certainly doesn't work for HEIC and MOV files at the moment.